# How to return int or nil in golang?

Tags: go

I'm a java developer and I am learning Go.
 I'm writing simple 'pop' operation for a LIFO stack. The question is with the return value when there are no values in the stack. In java, I'm able to return a wrapper(Integer) in the positive case and null when there are no values. It's natural from my perspective.

How can I do something similar in Go? Are there any struct wrappers for primitives? Do I need to return two values(the second will indicate error code)? Or do I need to throw an exception?

Here's how it looks for now:

```
func (s *stack) Pop() (int, bool)  {
    if s.size == 0 {
        return 0, true
    }
    s.size--
    val := s.stack[s.size]
    return val, false
}
```

Is it good style?

Comment: You could return an `*int`. Not sure if that’s nice, though.

Comment: Please note that the language is called "Go". Two letters, the first one capitalized. "golang" is a part of the domain name and a special keyword understood by a popular search engine owned by a company where the development of Go originated.

Comment: Another point is that Go does not have exception (luckily). It has `panic()` and `recover()` but they are [not](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) [exceptions](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go); [treat errors as values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values), and consider [handling them gracefully](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully) ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since a number can't be `nil`, you can't return `nil` for integer, unless you define the return value as a pointer. The idiomatic solution in Go is by defining your method to return more than one values, e.g.

```
func (s *stack) Pop() (int, bool) {
    //does not exists
    if ... {
        return 0, false
    }

    //...

    //v is the integer value
    return v, true
}
```

Then somewhere you can call `Pop` as

```
s := &stack{}
if v, ok := s.Pop(); ok {
    //the value exists
}
```

Take a look at [comma, ok idiom](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps).

Comment: Thanks. Here's what i have for now. Please correct if something is not in 'go' style:

func (s *stack) Pop() (int, bool)  {
 if s.size == 0 {
  return 0, true
 }
 s.size--
 val := s.stack[s.size]
 return val, false
}

Comment: @the_kaba The first return should be: `return 0, false` and the second return should be `return val, true`.

Comment: what if we are using generic instead of `int` ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no `try/catch` constructs in Go, so you can't rely on that.

Go has instead a nice feature of allowing multiple return values. And their [error handling](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) is built on that.

So the canonical way to deal with the possibility of an exception is to return both a value and an error. After the operation, the error is checked and acted upon, ignoring the value. In your case you can keep the value as an `int`, and use a default value of `0` in the case of an error. Since clients would hopefully ignore the value in that case and do something about the error.

Comment: But what if stack can contain 0? It seems for me that from client side it will look ugly. For example, we know that 0 can indicate an error and we have second, boolean value that is true when we have exception:
if resp0 == 0 && resp1 == true {
// exception handling
}

Do you mean to write in this way?

Comment: You should _always_ check the error condition. So if you don't get an error, but the value poped is `0`, you know it's a good value. The test should simply be `if resp1 != nil { // exception handling }`. You don't look at `resp0`, until you know `resp1 == nil` and no error occurred. So you can trust `resp0` to be a valid value from the stack. Go is dogmatic that way. You should not ignore the error, and you should deal with it as soon as you can rather than in a `catch` close somewhere later.

Comment: Generally for such a simple case a boolean is used instead of an error, but this is correct for the general case. In both cases you should always check the error/boolean before doing anything else. There are many, many questions posted here where the answer would have been obvious had the asked checked the errors properly.