# How to Return Nil String in Go?

Tags: string, go, null

I have a function which returns a string under certain circumstances, namely when the program runs in Linux or MacOS, otherwise the return value should be nil in order to omit some OS-specific checks further in code.

```
func test() (response string) {
    if runtime.GOOS != "linux" {  
        return nil
    } else {
        /* blablabla*/
    }
}
```

however when I try to compile this code I get an error:

> test.go:10:3: cannot use nil as type string in return argument.

If I return just an empty string like `return ""`, I cannot compare this return value with `nil` further in code.

So the question is how to return a correct nil string value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return int or nil in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726832/how-to-return-int-or-nil-in-golang)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you can't use `""`, return a pointer of type `*string`; or–since this is Go–you may declare multiple return values, such as: `(response string, ok bool)`.

Using `*string`: return `nil` pointer when you don't have a "useful" string to return. When you do, assign it to a local variable, and return its address.

```
func test() (response *string) {
    if runtime.GOOS != "linux" {
        return nil
    } else {
        ret := "useful"
        return &ret
    }
}
```

Using multiple return values: when you have a useful string to return, return it with `ok = true`, e.g.:

```
return "useful", true
```

Otherwise:

```
return "", false
```

This is how it would look like:

```
func test() (response string, ok bool) {
    if runtime.GOOS != "linux" {
        return "", false
    } else {
        return "useful", true
    }
}
```

At the caller, first check the `ok` return value. If that's `true`, you may use the `string` value. Otherwise, consider it useless.

**Also see related questions:**

[How do I represent an Optional String in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731687/how-do-i-represent-an-optional-string-in-go/30741287#30741287)

Alternatives for obtaining and returning a pointer to `string`: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)

Comment: well, looks like returning string pointer instead of the string itself is the best way to avoid additional entities

Comment: @sotona Depends on how (and how often) you intend to use this function. Multi-return values are quite common in Go, and working with string pointers is more cumbersome. I'd go with multi-return values in most of the time.

Answer (score 11):

[Go has built-in support for multiple return values](https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values):

This feature is used often in idiomatic Go, [for example](https://gobyexample.com/errors) to return both result and error values from a function.

In your case it could be like this:

```
func test() (response string, err error) {
    if runtime.GOOS != "linux" {  
        return "", nil
    } else {
        /* blablabla*/
    }
}
```

And then:

```
response, err := test()
if err != nil { 
    // Error handling code
    return;
}

// Normal code
```

If you want to ignore the error, simply use `_`:

```
response, _ := test()
// Normal code
```

Answer (score 1):

Go allows multiple return types. So use this to your advantage and return an error or any other type. Check this out for more info: http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/return-values-from-go-functions.html?m=1