# How do I put value in optional string parameter in golang?

Tags: go

let say a function

```
func BuildRequest(string,string,string)
```

all three parameters are optional

```
`request, err := BuildRequest("","{}","")` --> incorrect
```

like in JS, Java, Python we have null, None but in golang `nil` is not from string family.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `*string`  for optionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the signature of the function (the signature is given), then it depends entirely on the implementation of the function. Most likely the empty string will represent the lack of actual argument value.

If you're free to choose the parameter type, then `*string` may be `nil` to represent `null` value. Or if you don't use the empty string value, denote that to be `null` and you may use `string` for convenience

See possible duplicates:

[How do I represent an Optional String in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731687/how-do-i-represent-an-optional-string-in-go/30741287#30741287)

[How to Return Nil String in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255683/how-to-return-nil-string-in-go/52255707#52255707)